# How to resize cells for size class swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, resize, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` in my app. I want it to constrain so it only has two cells on each horizontal row. For iPhone classes I achieve this by setting the width so three cells can't fit in the same horizontal row. This seems to be a fix but I don't know how to resize the cell for iPads. I have heard to use:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
```

but I can't access this function. Does Swift no longer support this function anymore?

Question: Can I force my screen to only display 2 cells on each horizontal row?

Comment: That method does still exist. But you can do it a variety of ways. How are you setting the size currently? Could you include that code?

Comment: That method has the wrong signature for Swift 3. See the documentation for the proper signature.

Answer (score 0):

You should first conform to protocol `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

and then implement the method :

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width * 0.5, height: 30)
    }
```

Comment: I get the Error "multiple inheritinces from classes 'UIViewController' and 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout''"

Comment: nevermind. I accidentaly added "UICollectionViewFlowLayout" instead of "UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout"